# How to enforce the screen reader to say something in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, accessibility

I am working with accessibility in Flutter and want to make the voice reader to say something to the user without the use of widgets for it.

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the SemanticsService for it:

```
SemanticsService.announce('I am saying something', TextDirection.ltr);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    static Future<void> announce(String message, TextDirection textDirection) async {
  final AnnounceSemanticsEvent event = AnnounceSemanticsEvent(message, textDirection);
  await SystemChannels.accessibility.send(event.toMap());
}
```

announce is method of SemanticsService class Which you can use as per below code

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Press me"),
          onPressed: () {
            SemanticsService.announce(
                "I've just been pressed", TextDirection.ltr);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Check Documentation https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/semantics/SemanticsService/announce.html